# Автодополнение в netbeans функциональное программирование

Tags: netbeans

Мне нужно что бы у меня автодополнялись функции из класса. Cтруктура кода сделана с помощью инклудов файлов, все сделано без использования ООП. Есть начальный файл где инициализируется переменная, допустим `$dbClass = new dbClass();`. Через несколько инклудов от этого места происходит другое присвоение `$subClass = $dbClass->getSubClass();` - возвращает объект класса. И вот теперь я хочу обращаясь к переменной `$subClass->` получать автодополнение всех методов класса `subClass`.

С помощью phpDoc в этом файле прописываю так

```
/**
* @property subClass $subClass
*/
```

или так

```
/**
* @param subClass $subClass
*/
```

и это не помогает.

Если в этом же файле создать класс, то в его методах автодополнение работает.

Интересно узнать, можно ли без класса, таким образом создать автодополние для переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какое "функциональное программирование без ооп" на классах?

Вам нужно написать PHPDoc для getSubClass():

```
/**
 * @return SubClass description
 */
public function getSubClass()
{
...
```

Comment: обычное, когда 1-2 класса всего встречаются, используются например для описания работы с базой, т.е. могут совсем не использоваться. 

Нет это тоже не помогает (

Comment: @oldy, странно, но попробуйте так:

    /**
     * @var $subClass SubClass
     */
    $subClass = $dbClass->getSubClass()

и сразу ссылка на всякий: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_variable_type_in_a

Comment: спасибо, то что надо. только почему то  
/**
 * @var $subClass SubClass
 */
не работает, а вот так работает
/* @var $subClass SubClass */